# Tikz - code suggestion?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

Tikz:

I would like to draw a figure in optics, a laser. See image. Can anybody help me? 
Any suggestion for code?

[image]

Here's the MWE:

```
\begin{figure}[htb] 
\centering 

% \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large] 

% Rektangel: \tikz \shade (0,0) rectangle (3,2); 
% (x,y) (x,y) \tikzset{LL/.style={draw=black, decorate, decoration={snake, segment length=3mm, amplitude=2mm,post length=2mm}}} 

% \draw[LL,->,>=latex,thick,black](0,1) -- (4,1)node[right]{$\ket{\alpha e^{-2i\omega t}}$}; 

% % \end{tikzpicture} 

% \caption{Strong laser described by $\ket{\alpha e^{-2i\omega t}}$.}
\label{fig:M1} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Do you already have a piece of code to start?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: @PKR Which figure do you want to draw actually? Do you need the comments inside the yellow rectangles to be drawn?

Comment: @pushpen.paul I want to draw a laser (rectangle) and the light (wave). This it. Such that it looks nice.

Comment: You should at least attempt to this yourself rather than asking someone to do everything for you. Inside a `tikzpicture` environment `\draw[red](0,0)--(2,0)--(2,0.8)--(3,0.8)--(3,0)--(3.5,1);` is a good start towards drawing your box with an arrow.

Comment: \begin{figure}[htb]  
\centering
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large]
  % Rektangel:
  \tikz \shade (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
  %            (x,y)           (x,y) 
  \tikzset{LL/.style={draw=black, decorate, decoration={snake, segment length=3mm, amplitude=2mm,post length=2mm}}}
  %  
  \draw[LL,->,>=latex,thick,black](0,1) -- (4,1)node[right]{$\ket{\alpha e^{-2i\omega t}}$};
  %
  %
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\caption{Strong laser described by $\ket{\alpha e^{-2i\omega t}}$.} \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}

Comment: The text above is my suggestion for the code. (How to I add picture and grey environment to indicate that the above is code? Tried to find out, but couldn't make it).

Comment: @PKR Please consider editing your question after inserting your code (MWE) with formatting.

Comment: @pushpen.paul  I have tried to read how to format questions. I have e.g. read "Comments use min-Markdown formatting". However, I still don't understand how to edit my questions. I agree that my questions are messy resented when I don't format them. Can you help me? How does this work?

Comment: @PKR I have edited your question. It will be publicly visible once approved by peer reviewers. `:-)`

Comment: @PKR To format code, either indent it by 4 spaces or select it and click the `{}` button.

Answer (score 3):

From your "MWE" i conclude, that you maybe like to draw something like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usepackage{braket}
    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    font = \large,
       > = angle 90,
L/.style = {decoration={snake, pre=lineto, pre length=2mm},
            very thick, red}
                        ]
\node[draw,minimum width=30mm,minimum height=20mm,
      pattern=north east lines]    (n1) {};
\draw[decorate,L,<-] (n1) to node[above] {$\ket{\alpha e^{-2i\omega t}}$} +(-44mm,0mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Strong laser described by $\ket{\alpha e^{-2i\omega t}}$.}
    \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm starting to understand how it works.  One more thing: I would like to show my suggestion to code. And teh final result in a picture. But I still don't understand how I do it. T. Verron says: "either indent it by 4 spaces or select it and click the {} button". 4 spaces? "    ". Like this       code here? And the {} button? There is no such button on the keyboard? ) I feel stupid now.)